# Fedora 25 Workstation : Anaconda throws Traceback error during installation

Tags: fedora, python, vmware, installer-anaconda

I'm trying to install Fedora 25 Workstation on Lenovo Ideapad.
Using VMWare Player with 20GB HDD space, 2GB RAM, 2 Processor core.
Installation goes fine till stage 2 where Anaconda tries to create the User.
Then, it shows a pop up that an error has occurred.
Following is the error:

```
The following was filed automatically by anaconda:
anaconda 25.20.8-1 exception report
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pyanaconda/users.py", line 379,     in createUser
    raise OSError("Unable to create user %s: status=%s" % (user_name, status))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pyanaconda/kickstart.py", line 1801, in execute
    users.createUser(usr.name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pyanaconda/install.py", line 95, in doConfiguration
    ksdata.user.execute(storage, ksdata, instClass, u)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pyanaconda/threads.py", line 251, in run
    threading.Thread.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
OSError: Unable to create user 0111: status=3

Additional info:
addons:         com_redhat_kdump
cmdline:        /usr/bin/python3  /sbin/anaconda --liveinst --  method=livecd:///dev/mapper/live-base
cmdline_file:   BOOT_IMAGE=vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img  root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-25-1-3 rd.live.image quiet
executable:     /sbin/anaconda
hashmarkername: anaconda
kernel:         4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
other involved packages: system-python-libs-3.5.2-4.fc25.x86_64
product:        Fedora
release:        Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
type:           anaconda
version:        25
```

Also please note, that I have installed LinuxMint and Lubuntu in VMWare Player with same configurations in same machine and they are working without such problems. Hoping to fix this and move to fedora soon!

Answer (score 2):

Known bug, [Bugzilla : OSError: Unable to create user 1234: status=3](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1339237).  Caused by trying to create a bogus username.

Fix is to not request bogus usernames.

> Anaconda interface should show an error message when an invalid User Name is entered and pressed Done.
>
> Note: From man page of adduser it says "Usernames must start with a lower case letter or an underscore, followed by lower case letters, digits, underscores, or dashes. They can end with a dollar sign.  In regular expression terms: **[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?**